# Implementing a simple NAT using scapy

Tags: python, scapy, mininet, icmp

So the topology is like this: H1(192.168.1.2)---S1---(192.168.1.1)H3(20.0.0.1)---S2---H2(20.0.0.2)... and I'm trying to implement a simple NAT script using scapy in H3.

```
from scapy.all import *
def handlePacket(pkt):
        if pkt.sniffed_on == "h3-eth0":
                if IP in pkt and ICMP in pkt:
                        if pkt[IP].src=="192.168.1.2" and pkt[IP].dst == "20.0.0.2":
                                pkt[IP].src="20.0.0.3"
                                pkt[Ether].dst= None
                                sendp(pkt,iface="h3-eth1")
         elif pkt.sniffed_on == "h3-eth1":
                if IP in pkt and ICMP in pkt:
                        if pkt[IP].src=="20.0.0.2" and pkt[IP].dst=="20.0.0.3":
                                pkt[IP].dst="192.168.1.2"
                                pkt[Ether].dst= None
                                sendp(pkt,iface="h3-eth0")
if __name__ == "__main__":
        sniff(filter="icmp",iface=["h3-eth0","h3-eth1"],prn=handlePacket)
```

[Here, H2 receives the ICMP packet but doesn't give reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dp5JN.png)

> Frame 7: 98 bytes on wire (784 bits), 98 bytes captured (784 bits) on interface h2-eth0, id 0
> Ethernet II, Src: 52:a8:79:2d:6f:cf (52:a8:79:2d:6f:cf), Dst: 36:34:00:71:f8:51 (36:34:00:71:f8:51)
> Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 20.0.0.3, Dst: 20.0.0.2

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Please edit your question to include formatted text, not images of text (for code and for your packet capture). See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why this is important.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Yeah, so sorry.. I'm new here.. I've made changes now

Comment: Can you [edit] your post to contain the packet capture in a text format?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark yeah, sure.. I've made the changes.

Comment: I fail to see any NAT configuration. Looks to me like you are trying to modify a packet by changing the destination/source address. That won't work unless you somehow proxy all traffic through scapy first.

Comment: On the topology you describe the IP address of H3 on eth1 is `20.0.0.1` while in the code when performing the translation you put `20.0.0.3`. If `20.0.0.1` is truly the IP of H3.eth1, then the problem comes from that : H2 performs an ARP request to learn the MAC address of `20.0.0.3` which will obviously fail.